# WebTestClient does not behave normally with chained Mono.onErrorResume

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am getting my hands on reactive programming for my job now, hence working on my first ever Webflux application as practice.

I am using relatively straightforward approach, in my functional endpoint `TaskHandler`, I have a `createTask` method:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createTask(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<TaskDto> taskToCreate = request
                .bodyToMono(TaskDto.class)
                .flatMap(body -> HandlerUtils.validateAndReturn(body, validator))
                .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                    log.error("Error on createTask method: ", ex);
                    if(ex instanceof TaskMgmtException) return Mono.error(ex);
                    return Mono.error(new TaskMgmtException(TaskError.TE_004));
                });

        return taskService.create(taskToCreate)
                .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                    log.error("Error at createTask method: ", ex);
                    if(ex instanceof TaskMgmtException) return Mono.error(ex);
                    return Mono.error(new TaskMgmtException(TaskError.TE_001));
                })
                .flatMap(taskDto -> {
                    CommonResponse<TaskDto> commonResponse = new CommonResponse<>();
                    commonResponse.setSuccess(true);
                    commonResponse.setTimeStamp(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
                    commonResponse.setData(taskDto);

                    return ServerResponse
                            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .bodyValue(commonResponse);
                });
    }
```

whereas in my `TaskService`, I have a `create` method:

```
@Override
    public Mono<TaskDto> create(Mono<TaskDto> taskDto) {
        return taskDto
                .onErrorResume(ex -> {
                    log.error("Error on create method", ex);
                    if(ex instanceof TaskMgmtException) return Mono.error(ex);
                    return Mono.error(new TaskMgmtException(TaskError.TE_005));
                })
                .flatMap(task -> {
                    Task taskToAdd = new Task();

                    taskToAdd.setTitle(task.getTitle());
                    taskToAdd.setDescription(task.getDescription());
                    taskToAdd.setDueDate(task.getDueDate());
                    taskToAdd.setStatus(task.getTaskStatus());

                    return taskRepository.save(taskToAdd).map(TaskMapper.TASK_MAPPER::toDto);
                });
    }
```

These chained streams both has `.onErrorResume`, so that I can fine-grain the error type myself. Eg: if error happens on service layer, TE_005 indicating DB error, whereas if it happens on handler layer, such as the failed validation, TE_004 indicating invalid input.

In my unit test,

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RouterConfig.class, TaskHandler.class, GlobalExceptionHandler.class})
@WebFluxTest(TaskHandler.class)
public class TaskHandlerUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @MockBean
    TaskService taskService;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    private final List<TaskDto> taskList = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        webTestClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).build();
        // code to add dummy Task
    }

    
    @Test
    void testCreateTaskFail() {
        TaskDto incompleteTaskDto = new TaskDto();
        Mockito.when(taskService.create(any(Mono.class))).thenReturn(Mono.error(
                new TaskMgmtException(TaskError.TE_005)
        ));

        webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/tasks")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .bodyValue(incompleteTaskDto)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isBadRequest()
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.success").isEqualTo(false)
                .jsonPath("$.data").isEmpty();

        verify(taskService, times(1)).create(any(Mono.class));
    }
    // other test cases

}
```

This test case fails at `.expectStatus().isBadRequest()` and says expected status to be `Internal Server Error` which reflects to my `TE_005`. But when tested using Postman, everything is working fine.

Is there anything wrong with my unit test configuration? Please let me know if you have any feedbacks on the code as well. Thanks!

Comment: And why shouldn't it? You are returning a `TE_005` from your service, that is what you told the mock to do.

Comment: that...i did not notice, thank you for pointing it out. Also on the other note, to make this test case valid, i should have expected the `testCreateTaskFail` to not enter service layer at all, hence making sure error from `HandlerUtils.validateAndReturn(body, validator)` will not be preceded by error from service layer

Comment: It doesn't enter the service nor is your `taskToCreate` `Mono` of any use. As what you instructed the service to to is throw an error. It will simply not call anything.

Comment: i see, i get what you mean now, i misunderstood the `.onErrorResume` as if it will stop propagating into service layer when `onError` signal is returned. Turns out the `taskToCreate` did returned a `onError` signal, but i instrucuted my service method to do differently. Will write an answer to wrap this up, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I misunderstood the flow of stream in my code. While getting `taskToCreate` my my handler method, it did returned a `onError` signal, instead of completing the stream and directly return the `TE_004` http response like I initially thought, the `taskToCreate` propagates to the `taskService.create` and from there its up to the `onErrorResume` in my `create` method to decide how to complete (or technically propagates) the stream.

So the fix was to modify the instruction to `create` in the mocked service layer to return `TE_004` instead of `TE_005`.

```
// since an onError signal TE_004 is initially passed to this method 
// just return it back as if how the real service method would react
Mockito.when(taskService.create(any(Mono.class))).thenReturn(Mono.error(
                new TaskMgmtException(TaskError.TE_004)
        ));
```